# General queries about polygon pour - PCB Design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I finally decided to build my very own battery operated GPS device. So I started designing the PCB and i am having hard time understanding certain things.

Here are the details of the board

- 2-Layer board.
- Contains GPS receiver and Bluetooth 4.1
- Battery Management unit ( with charging current of 2A )
- A Buck-Boost Converter  ( 1.6Mhz, ILmax= 1.2A)
- Controller with 32Mhz Crystal

  How do I decide if I need a Polygon pour? Should the poly always be ground? How does poly affect the performance of the GPS or BLE?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a pretty complicated board for your first attempt. Be prepared for multiple respins.

Comment: In most cases, polygon pour helps. However if there is an antenna, you need to be a little careful. Not only about polygon pour but complete PCB layout as a whole might affect the performance of BT and GPS. Also there are cases where you don't want a single pour for whole PCB. For ex - When analog and digital circuit are present together. If you post the board layout, people here will be able to guide you into right direction much comfortably.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack will be posting it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

In general, **polygon pours** are used for ground and power rails. It depends on the layout and the requirements of the circuit. They are "just" copper and they can be used for many purposes: electrical connection, grounding, thermal relief, reference plane for a controlled impedance track, inter-plane coupling...

They can affect the performance of the GPS and BL as any other layout feature. They are part of the whole layout.

===

Regarding your project, it sounds kind of complex PCB.

Before thinking about polygon pours you should sketch a first schematics and then start to think about the PCB.

Some questions that may help for the PCB design:

- How many power rails do i need?
- What are the power requirements of each power rail?
- Do I have a fine pitch packages like BGA or QFN? How many layers do I need to fan out these packages?
- Do I need any controlled impedance track for the RF section?

Probably you would need 4 layer PCB and consider controlled-impedance tracks.

Comment: +1 for mentioning controlled impedance. At the frequencies used they would definitely be a good idea